# Issue with loadbalancer with magento on amazon

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services

I have setup a load balancer on amazon and set 4 instances connected with it.

I have installed apache there and it is working perfectly fine. However when I installed Magento on one of my instances, It is going out of service all of a sudden.

I tried debugging it in index.php where when I put die above where app/mage.php is getting included  it is working fine till then but when I leave it like original, it is getting out of service? is the htaccess of app folder creating any issue? Is there any mistake I am doing. What is wrong with putting Magento in one instance and as the matter of fact into all 4 instances also.

Comment: Could it be that your _health check_ is set to check a specific URL (e.g. index.html, the default, which produces 404 in magento) that is not accessible by the magento instance? You could try to change it to do TCP ping in stead.

Comment: Nirmesh, please accept my answer if it helped you, or let me know if it didn't. It is good custom on SO to accept answers to your questions when people take out time to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your *Health Check* for the load-balancer is the problem.

The default setting is HTTP ping of index.html. Visiting `/index.html` on magento produces a 404, thus makes your load-balancer think that the instance is out. Putting in the `die()` results in return code 200 which is why you see it working.

Either change the URL to check to `/index.php` or something else that does not produce a 404. Or you could change the type of the check to TCP.

From this (HTTP):

[image: From this]

To something like this (TCP):

[image: To this]